# Merge [rules] into [policies]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

[policies](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/policies) currently has two questions and [rules](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules) has four.  These don't seem sufficiently distinct to me.  Can we either clarify the difference (via tag wikis, please) or merge them (and create a synonym)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the distinction being made in [this answer](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/150/83) is too nuanced for this site; that's not how everybody actually uses those words and maintaining two tags with that distinction is not going to work out well.  We should definitely not have two tags.

However, combining them into a single [rules-and-policies](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-and-policies) tag would be acceptable; anybody who starts typing either "rules" or "policies" will get there (no synonyms needed).

Answer (score 3):

As per definition a rule is a procedure that **must** be followed, however a policy is more of a guidline. As a quick example

- By viewing forum A you accept that you will not spam, if you do you
  will be banned. *This is a rule **not** a policy*
- As a general policy being a forum based in the US, we will only
  provide official support to English posted questions *this is a
  policy, it's **not** against the rules*
- And another example is *Honesty is the best policy*, you don't have to be honest.

If they were to be merged I would like to see it as [rules-and-policies](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-and-policies)

Comment: *Technically* you're right about the distinction, but I don't think it tends to be so distinct out in the wild.  A combined tag would be ok.

Comment: I added the last bit for merging if it were to happen.